# How to extract JWT Expiry date without resource server?

Tags: authentication, jwt, amazon-cognito

I have a Single Page Application which requests JWTs from AWS cognito to access protected resources in a resource server. However, when the JWT expires, I would like to programmatically refresh it. To do this, I need to know if the token is expired to trigger a refresh. Here is the JWT below.

```
{
      "sub": "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee",
      "aud": "xxxxxxxxxxxxexample",
      "email_verified": true,
      "token_use": "id",
      "auth_time": 1500009400,
      "iss": "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_example",
      "cognito:username": "janedoe",
      "exp": 1500013000, // <---- this is what we want
      "given_name": "Jane",
      "iat": 1500009400,
      "email": "janedoe@example.com"
      }
```

My dilemma however is that I do not know how to check when it expires without sending it to the resource server to validate it and I cannot do validation on front end as that would expose application secrets. I figure the `exp` variable is possibly the number of milliseconds from a particular date, however I'm not sure (and nothing on Google corroborates this).

So I'd like to ask, how does one determine the expiry date from the `exp` variable?

Comment: What is SPA? ..

Comment: Single Page Application (I'll update the question to reflect this)

Comment: at resource server, did u apply any mechanism to respond Expire token? If not you have to do that at server. then  Base on the response from the server you will refresh it at frontend. In angular, you can do it at interceptor.

Answer (score 3):

The `exp` claim is indeed what you're looking for. It's the [expiration time](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4), encoded as a [numeric value](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4) representing [the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-2) (also refered to as UNIX Epoch time)

You can check your token on https://jwt.io/ and see the converted timestamp, if you point with the mouse on the numeric timestamp.

Here's a small js snippet, that demonstrates how you can calculate the remaining time:

```js
// exp = 2019-09-01 00:00 UTC
var exp = 1567296000
var currentTimeSeconds = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);
console.log(currentTimeSeconds)
var remainingSeconds = exp - currentTimeSeconds
console.log(remainingSeconds + " seconds remaining")
```

and here is how to convert it to date type, output in local time:

```js
// exp = 2019-09-01 00:00 UTC
var exp = 1567296000

var expDate = new Date(exp*1000);

var expYear =  expDate.getYear() + 1900
var expMonth = expDate.getMonth() + 1
var expDay = expDate.getDate() 
var expHours = "0" + expDate.getHours()
var expMinutes = "0" + expDate.getMinutes()
var expSeconds = "0" + expDate.getSeconds()
var expFormatted = expYear + "-" + expMonth + "-" + expDay + " " + expHours.substr(-2) + ':' + expMinutes.substr(-2) + ':' + expSeconds.substr(-2);
console.log(expFormatted)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cognito provides some standard session validation in their libraries.

If you're using JavaScript, you can get a valid set of tokens using

```
CognitoUser.getSession((err, session) => {
  ... 
})
```

This checks the id and access tokens and if either is expired, will retrieve updated tokens using the refresh token.